# How can you get the thumnail URLS given the original image URL?

Tags: image, spfile

Given only a URL like `/PublishingImages/lorem-ipsum.jpg` how can i get the two thumbnail URLs?

Both the `_t` and the `_w` thumbnail URLs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I whipped this little method up.

```
public string image_thumbnail(object existing_url, string type)
{
    string url = existing_url.ToString();

    if (type.Length == 0)
        return url;

    string ext = url.Substring(url.LastIndexOf("."));

    return (url.Substring(0, url.LastIndexOf(".")) + ext.Replace(".", "_") + ".jpg").Insert(url.LastIndexOf("/"), "/" + type);
}
```

Implemented like so:

```
string thumbnail = image_thumbnail("/PublishingImages/lorem-ipsum.jpg", "_t");
```

`thumbnail` == `/PublishingImages/_t/lorem-ipsum_jpg.jpg`